# Access Rounding

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Is there a reason Access rounds Round(19.5,0) and Round(20.5,0) both to 20?  Shouldnt the first return 20 and the second return 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Round function utilizes **round-to-even** logic. If the expression that you are rounding ends with a 5, the Round function will round the expression so that the last digit is an even number. For example:

```
Round (12.55, 1)
Result: 12.6   (rounds up)

Round (12.65, 1)
Result: 12.6   (rounds down)

Round (12.75, 1)
Result: 12.8   (rounds up)
```

In these cases, the last digit after rounding is always an even number. So, be sure to only use the Round function if this is your desired result.

See http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php

Answer (score 4):

Access uses Bankers Rounding (AKA Round Half to Even).

See: http://allenbrowne.com/round.html

> When the last significant digit is a 5, it rounds to the nearest even
>   number. So, 0.125 rounds to 0.12 (2 is even), whereas 0.135 rounds to
>   0.14 (4 is even.)